# splitting text file data into columns

Tags: sql, text

Hello all I had a text file in which it contains thousands of lines/records and they are in the following format

```
6242S10TH AVENUE                    KWANOBUHLE                    Y 6242
```

the space between these words are also inconsistent.so, now I just want to split this data into three separate columns so as to make a table.

Comment: If you know perl, try using pattern match :)

Comment: Is there always at least more than one space between the separate column words - if not how can you tell where one column ends and another begins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume this:

- There is at least three spaces between colums
- A column value doesn't contain as much as three spaces
- There are no empty column values

You can split a line on three spaces and trim the values. C# example:

```
string[] columns =
  line.Split(new string[]{"   "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(s => s.Trim())
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class mentioned here--> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.100).aspx will be helpful